# how to avoid accessing to the property in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Newbie for d3.js here.  I tried to get access to the property of each data, but some data does not have property.  I get the following error message when I tried to access a property that data does not have.

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property*

> color(data[d.id][property])

```
var change = function() {
      val = d3.event.target.value;
      d3.selectAll("path").style("fill", function(d) {
        // in this case val might be the property of the data[d.id], so that i 
        // want to escape this case. 
        color(data[d.id][val]); // data is a global variable

      });
 }
```

My question is how do I simply skip access that specific property to avoid this type error?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try checking for undefined before accessing property. also if you are using chrome then its developer tool gives nice console where u can debug source

Comment: It depends on the situation. Is that inside an `if` statement, or an anonymous function? How are you getting that property?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado it is in a anonymous function.Any suggestion?

Comment: If you don't show **how** are you using that it will be dificult to help you.

Comment: @sure, give me a sec, let me add something to the question

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I just edited my question, I am not sure if it is clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to check if that property exists. One of them is using a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
d3.selectAll("path").style("fill", function(d) {
    return data[d.id][val] ? color(data[d.id][val]) : "#ccc"
});
```

In that case, if the property exists, the anonymous function will return `color(data[d.id][val])`, if it doesn't, it will return `#ccc` (change this color according to your needs).